# nginx - streaming response to client, but also caching

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, chunked-encoding

I have what appear to be competing desires with nginx, but both of them seem like something you'd want.

I am using `nginx` as a reverse proxy to a python HTTP API server. Let's assume there is a single endpoint, and the result is a *very* large JSON document (multiple gigabytes).

One the one hand, I'm streaming my response to the client using http chunked encoding. This allows me to not hold the entire response object in python all at once - i can serialize and send chunks of the json at a time. (Side note, I plan to use https://jsonlines.org to avoid the json envelope in the near future.)

On the other hand, I'd like to use nginx proxy caching to hold the entire response on disk, and when the same request comes in, I don't have to stress the python server since nginx can just serve the static file from disk.

This brings me to my question: `proxy_buffering` within nginx appears to be required to be `on` for nginx response caching to work, but `off` for chunked encoding (streaming) response to stream immediately. I can't seem to find if nginx has a buffer size that flushes the buffer to the client (and the cache) every so often - I'd be very happy for a pointer to that information.

Is there a way to get both of the things I want here? Serving a streaming response, but caching that entire response for the next request? Should I explore other options, like varnish?

Thanks very much for any help/advice/pointers!

Answer (score 1):

No idea how to setup Nginx for streaming + caching, but I can confirm you the behaviour you are looking for is the way any recent Varnish Cache server behaves out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out as soon as i can.

Comment: I can't find confirmation of this behavior in any documentation, github issues, or PRs.